# Calling methods of object in Scala dynamically with scala.reflect.runtime.universe?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'd like to dynamically execute the methods that start with `removeAt` of the object `X` at runtime.

How can I do that with the `scala.reflect.runtime.universe` API described in [REFLECTION Environment, Universes, and Mirrors](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html)

Comment: why not to use [scala dynamic](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/type-dynamic.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution for your problem:

```
object X { 
   def aa = 1 
   def ab = 2
   def removeAtX = 3
   def bb = 4
   def removeAtY = 5 
}

val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val im = m.reflect(X)
val l = X.getClass.getMethods.map(_.getName).filter(_ startsWith "removeAt")
val r = l.map(y => ru.typeOf[X.type].declaration(ru.newTermName(y)).asMethod).map(im.reflectMethod(_).apply())
```

Result:

```
r: scala.collection.mutable.ArraySeq[Any] = ArraySeq(3, 5)
```